# No bootable medium after installing grub on laptop Acer Aspire

Tags: boot, grub, manjaro

I've installed a new Manjaro Linux 16.06.1 on an Aspire V15 Nitro Vn7-572G-56VP. Before, there was a Linpus Linux installed. I recreated all partitions and installed Manjaro. I also attempted the manual grub install from https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader . `grub-install --recheck` ran without errors.

But now the laptop boots and cannot find any bootable media. No grub boot menu is shown.

I also tried enabling Secure Boot and adding grubx64.efi to the trusted files.

What can I do?

Here is some info that might be useful (sda is an SSD, sdb is a HDD):

```
>>> bootinfoscript
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub Legacy is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    59737416 of the same hard drive for the stage2 file, but no stage2 files 
    can be found at this location..
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/manjaro/grubx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Manjaro Linux () ()
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   500,118,191   500,118,191  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     8,390,655     8,388,608 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       8,390,656   500,117,503   491,726,848 Data partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1   976,773,167   976,773,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1           2,048   976,773,119   976,771,072 Data partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        D422-C962                              vfat       
/dev/sda2        b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25   ext4       linux
/dev/sdb1        0bac8e21-a536-4061-9986-2abea769d215   ext4       hdd
/dev/sr0         2016-06-11-22-41-35-00                 iso9660    MJRO1606

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sr0         /bootmnt                 iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="${saved_entry}"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

set menu_color_normal=light-gray/black
set menu_color_highlight=green/black

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
fi
insmod png
background_image -m stretch /usr/share/grub/background.png
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Manjaro Linux' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25' {
    savedefault
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
    linux    /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64 root=UUID=b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25 rw  quiet splash
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd    /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Manjaro Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25' {
    menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64-advanced-b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25' {
    savedefault
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
        linux    /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64 root=UUID=b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25 rw  quiet splash
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd    /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Manjaro Linux (Kernel: 4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64 - fallback initramfs)' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64-fallback-b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.13-1-MANJARO x64 ...'
        linux    /boot/vmlinuz-4.4-x86_64 root=UUID=b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25 rw  quiet splash
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd    /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.4-x86_64-fallback.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/60_memtest86+ ###
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "pc" ]; then
    menuentry "Memory Tester (memtest86+)" --class memtest86 --class gnu --class tool {
        search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25
        linux16 /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin 
    }
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/60_memtest86+ ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                           <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=0bac8e21-a536-4061-9986-2abea769d215 /hdd           ext4    defaults,noatime 0       2
UUID=b30147d2-e13f-4651-9263-60341c46de25 /              ext4    defaults,noatime,discard 0       1
UUID=7D0D-278F                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0       2
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

======================= sda2/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: =======================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Config file for Syslinux -
# /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg
#
# Comboot modules:
#   * menu.c32 - provides a text menu
#   * vesamenu.c32 - provides a graphical menu
#   * chain.c32 - chainload MBRs, partition boot sectors, Windows bootloaders
#   * hdt.c32 - hardware detection tool
#   * reboot.c32 - reboots the system
#
# To Use: Copy the respective files from /usr/lib/syslinux to /boot/syslinux.
# If /usr and /boot are on the same file system, symlink the files instead
# of copying them.
#
# If you do not use a menu, a 'boot:' prompt will be shown and the system
# will boot automatically after 5 seconds.
#
# Please review the wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux
# The wiki provides further configuration examples

DEFAULT arch
PROMPT 0        # Set to 1 if you always want to display the boot: prompt
TIMEOUT 50
# You can create syslinux keymaps with the keytab-lilo tool
#KBDMAP de.ktl

# Menu Configuration
# Either menu.c32 or vesamenu32.c32 must be copied to /boot/syslinux
UI menu.c32
#UI vesamenu.c32

# Refer to http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/Doc/menu
MENU TITLE Arch Linux
#MENU BACKGROUND splash.png
MENU COLOR border       30;44   #40ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR title        1;36;44 #9033ccff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR sel          7;37;40 #e0ffffff #20ffffff all
MENU COLOR unsel        37;44   #50ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR help         37;40   #c0ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR timeout_msg  37;40   #80ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR timeout      1;37;40 #c0ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR msg07        37;40   #90ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR tabmsg       31;40   #30ffffff #00000000 std

# boot sections follow
#
# TIP: If you want a 1024x768 framebuffer, add "vga=773" to your kernel line.
#
#-*

LABEL arch
    MENU LABEL Arch Linux
    LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux
    APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
    INITRD ../initramfs-linux.img

LABEL archfallback
    MENU LABEL Arch Linux Fallback
    LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux
    APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
    INITRD ../initramfs-linux-fallback.img

#LABEL windows
#        MENU LABEL Windows
#        COM32 chain.c32
#        APPEND hd0 1

LABEL hdt
        MENU LABEL HDT (Hardware Detection Tool)
        COM32 hdt.c32

LABEL reboot
        MENU LABEL Reboot
        COM32 reboot.c32

LABEL poweroff
        MENU LABEL Poweroff
        COM32 poweroff.c32
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sda2: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-NjjdvYuk/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-NjjdvYuk/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

and

```
>>> ls -R /boot/efi
ls -R /boot/efi
/boot/efi:
EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
manjaro

/boot/efi/EFI/manjaro:
grubx64.efi
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it works if you use `bootloader-id="Windows Boot Manager"`. This seems to be hard-coded into the Acer Aspire notebook.